# Идиомы - значения

Tags: идиомы

На английском форуме отвечал на вопрос - и усомнился в правильности своего понимания русских выражений.

Вопрос такой.

Есть несколько идиом.
"Высосать из пальца", "Взять с потолка", "получить методом тыка", "изобретать велосипед". 
Вопрос такой. Есть ли у них что-то общее в значении и, если есть, как это общее обозначить максимально полно. Ну и чем, собственно, они различаются.

Comment: Не закрыта тема.----------

Answer (score 3):

Во всех этих фразеологизмах есть значение "изобретать (придумывать) что-либо не имея достаточной базы знаний (основания)".

Взял с потолка и высосал из пальца значит, что без оснований выдвинул ни на чём (или на недостоверных фактах) не основанное предположение.
Изобретать велосипед  - не имея должной базы знаний придумывать то, что уже придумали до тебя.
Методом тыка - без достаточной базы знаний находить решение методом проб и ошибок.

Различия тоже есть.
Высосать из пальца и взять с потолка - быть неправым. Причём из пальца высасывают, вообще без оснований, на ровном месте, а с потолка основания какие-то есть, но ложные или надуманные.

Изобретать велосипед и метод тыка - решать верно, но неправильным методом.
Велосипед изобретают, если неизвестно о более простых и эффективных методах, а методом тыка приходится пользоваться, когда не могут выявить причину из следствия и "лечат симптомы, а не болезнь".

Comment: Итак, что общего, если есть? О различиях - потом.

"изобретать (придумывать) что-либо не имея достаточной базы знаний (основания)" - это в принципе подходит, но сомнительно, что это... как бы сказать... максимально охватывает **все** общее. Чего-то явно остается за рамками.

Подробнее можете посмотреть на английском форуме.

Comment: Первые 2 абзаца - сходства, вторые - отличия.

Comment: @behemothus, Только сейчас увидел изменения в комментарии, поэтому отвечаю с запозданием.

Я сомневаюсь, что все эти фразеологизмы вообще вписываются в прокрустово ложе моего определения. Из-за того, что "высосать из пальца" можно что угодно пришлось добавить слова в скобках, которых первоначально не было, и я не уверен, что не забыл других вариантов использования выражений.

Правда, если сузить контекст, например научная работа, то можно расширить и общее значение.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, разница есть.
"Высосать из пальца" — это, скорее, надумать нечто, преувеличить. Например, "высосанная из пальца проблема".
"Взять с потолка" — действительно, нечто беспочвенное, придуманное на ходу, не имеющее подтверждения и реальной опоры.
"Изобретать велосипед" — искать пути решения чего-то, для чего это пути не только есть, но и всем известны.

Comment: Я понимаю, что есть разница. Я ищу прежде всего ответ на вопрос, что общего, если оно есть.  
  
Понимаете, я предложил эти варианты для перевода английского сочетания "guess and facked" (сам перевод тут не обсуждаем), а потом крепко усомнился, ну не может же быть так, чтобы не имеющие ничего общего русские идиомы соответствовали одному английскому... если определимся с общим, вопрос о различиях станет гораздо понятнее. Это философия, однако)))

Answer (score 0):

может быть,фантазия.